# Multiple items in TextBox Header property

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using WinRT-Xaml and I am trying to create a header on my textbox that has two different font styles.

I would normally do something like this to achieve it:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource RightNavHeaderTextBox}" Text="{Binding Contact.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <TextBox.Header>
        <Run Text="First Name" />
        <Run Text="(required)" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" />
    </TextBox.Header>
</TextBox>
```

But that gives me the build error of: "This Member 'Header has more than one item, use the Items property"

How do I get around this error? or is there a better way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource RightNavHeaderTextBox}" Text="{Binding Contact.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <TextBox.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="First Name" />
            <Run Text="(required)" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" />
        </TextBlock>
    </TextBox.Header>
</TextBox>
```